# gob: type mismatch: no fields matched compiling decoder - Golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using PubSub on two different streams where we receive messages from one stream, run some logic, and if it fits certain criteria, we publish it to the second stream. The second stream is also being received from in a goroutine.

Now, I have two main functions `HandleMessage` and `HandleRetry` where the former is from the first stream, and the second is for the second stream.

The relevant code for `HandleMessage` is as follows:

```golang
    if c.handler.ShouldProcess(tx) {
        err := c.handler.Process(tx)
        if err != nil {
            c.log.
                WithError(err).
                WithField("tx_hash", tx.TxHash.String()).
                Error("failed to process")

            retryMsg := RetryMessage{
                Transaction:                 tx,
                RemainingProcessingAttempts: c.config.MaxProcessingAttempts,
                LastAttempt:                 time.Now(),
            }

            data, err := pubsub.EncodeMessage(retryMsg)
            if err != nil {
                c.log.WithError(err).Error("failed to convert retry msg to byte slice")
            }

            id, err := c.retryQueue.Publish(context.Background(), &pubsub.Message{Data: data})
            if err != nil {
                c.log.WithError(err).
                    WithField("id", id).
                    Error("failed to publish message to retry queue")
            }
        }
    }
```

and in `HandleRetry`, the function opens with

```golang
    retryTx := new(RetryMessage)
    err := pubsub.DecodeMessage(msg.Data, retryTx)
    if err != nil {
        c.log.WithError(err).
            Error("failed to decode message: not a retry tx")
        msg.Ack()
        return
    }
```

For the `RetryQueue` which is handled by `HandleRetry` -- there is no other input except the messages being published from `HandleMessage`

But, I keep getting a gob decoding error saying

`level=error msg="failed to decode message: not a retry tx" env=LOCAL error="gob: type mismatch: no fields matched compiling decoder for RetryMessage"`

`RetryMessage` looks like this

```golang
type RetryMessage struct {
    Transaction                 *firehose.Transaction
    RemainingProcessingAttempts int
    LastAttempt                 time.Time
}
```

The encoding and decoding functions are as follows

```golang
// EncodeMessage convert an arbitrary interface into a byte slice.
func EncodeMessage(data interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)

    err := enc.Encode(data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}

// DecodeMessage decodes message data into the provided interface.
func DecodeMessage(data []byte, dest interface{}) error {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)
    return dec.Decode(dest)
}
```

Comment: Can you try print the type of dest before dec.Decode(dest). To make sure it is of type RetryMessage

Answer (score 0):

In this code in `HandleMessage`:

```
        data, err := pubsub.EncodeMessage(retryMsg)
        if err != nil {
            c.log.WithError(err).Error("failed to convert retry msg to byte slice")
        }
```

The error is ignored and the published message’s `data` field is populated with a potentially bad value. Check whether you are seeing “failed to convert retry msg to byte slice” in the logs.

Comment: I fixed the error, though it was unrelated. the gob decoder didn't like that the `Transaction` inside `RetryMessage` was a pointer, I changed it to be a copy of the struct and it worked

Comment: It would be best for you to add this answer and then accept it.